# Android app to quickly send a text string to a Windows computer via WiFi

Tags: windows, android, data, wifi, data-transfer

I'm looking for an Android app to quickly send a short (under 1K) text string from an Android device to a computer that does not have a camera.

I'm looking for a simple tool with the following requirements:

1. Transfer up to 1KB of data from an Android device to a Windows computer via WiFi.  If it also works to transfer data to a Linux computer, that's a big plus, but the only requirement is Android to Windows.
2. No using the internet ***whatsoever***.  The Android device will always be on the same WiFi network as the computer.
3. Very basic security.  Nothing special is needed here; the data just needs to be protected if someone happens to be capturing all the WiFi packets.  The network will always use at least WPA2 and we can assume for this use that there are no unauthorized devices on the network.
4. Fast with as few steps as possible.  Ideally, I would like to have a string in the Android clipboard, and with just 1 or 2 taps on Android, have the text sent to the computer.  The receiving app on Windows needs to be equally easy: ideally, just launch it and it will automatically be in "receive" mode.  If a "receive" button needs to be pressed, that's okay.  Overall, the whole process should take no more than 10 seconds combined on Android and Windows.
5. Gratis, or no more than the cost of a Grande Frappuccino with a way to buy it that doesn't involve Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Apple, Amazon, PayPal, or anything of their ilk.

Nice to have's (none required):

1. I would *prefer* the receiving app be a standalone app, and not a web browser.  This is a preference, and not a requirement.
2. Open-source code would be *very* nice on both ends.
3. Small footprint on both ends.  I'm looking for fast and efficient, without having to wait for some huge bloated Electron app to load.
4. Portable software on the Windows side (no writing to the registry or to the file system outside of its own folder).

Comment: Just as a thought, a very slick email application and a very basic email server on the Windows machine might work. You also might have luck finding a way to SSH to or from the phone, then pasting into a shared tmux session.